# What is the "processor" kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Recently, I wanted to make use of intel_powerclamp to limit the heat of my CPU. I activated it, and was unable to write to « cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state » to inject IDLE time (EINVAL, invalid argument).
When displaying the content of the « type » file in the cooling_device0 directory, it was not Powerclamp but Processor instead.

I had a hard time trying to change it, and resolved it by unloading the processor module and reloading intel_powerclamp.

Do you know what this "processor" kernel module is ? I have searched quite a lot and I am unable to figure out what it is, except that it's related to ACPI. And what is its purpose / what it can do ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Probably power saving management related. Modern, multiprocessor systems can shut down unused processors to save power.

Comment: @palkeo This site is actually not right for this kind of question. Actually...